# Planar immersion of circle not approximate embedding

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

On a topology preliminary exam, students in past years were asked to  find an immersion $f:S^1\to\Bbb R^2$ which cannot be approximated by an embedding (in the sense of the [weak Whitney theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem)).

I have an idea that seems reasonable: Trace out the Hawaiian earring, where the first $n$ circles are
   traversed between $0\leq\theta\leq 1-\frac1{2^n}$. This is a
   continuous map, and when we glue the pieces together at the origin we
   can probably do some partition of unity trick to avoid the abrupt
   change in magnitude of $f'$ that would otherwise occur when we changed pieces.

However, I can't figure out why there is no approximation by an embedding. I have some intuition: you have to end up on "one side" of a neighborhood of the origin, but you have to get back to the origin by $t=1$. This forces you to eventually leave the double of the neighborhood, but eventually the immersion says entirely inside the neighborhood. That seems problematic, although I'm not totally sure that those "eventually"s coincide enough to get an honest contradiction.

I'm interested in any answer to the question, but would be especially happy if you could talk about how to complete this argument, if it is true :P

Comment: So you have a typo in the first line? Embeddings of compact things are stable.

Comment: @Ted: Yep, should have been 'immersion'.

Comment: What is the definition of approximation here? I would have thought that meant finding an embedding arbitrarily close by. If that's the case, an infinity shape cannot be approximated by an embedding.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Sure it can, just trace the S-like shape that you get after you pull the two endpoints an arbitrarily small distance away from the center.

Comment: You still did not define what "approximate" means. (One cannot possibly answer a question without known what it is.) There are several possible interpretations of "approximate" in this context: (1) Hausdorff closeness of images, (2) in the sense of $C^k$-convergence for some $k\ge 0$ (to be specified). Choosing between (1) and (2) makes a difference.

Comment: @EricStucky: that is no longer an embedding of a circle.

Comment: @studiosus, I'm not sure what to tell you. It was part 2 of a question where part 1 was to state the Whitney embedding and immersion theorems, which seemed relevant, so I included that in my question. The requirements for the exam have since changed and so I don't know the text from which the students were studying. [Here is the exam](http://www.math.umn.edu/grad/Writtens/past_prelims/mantopS12.pdf), if you want the exact wording; the question is B1 (ii).

Comment: I suppose I can say this: Because of the Whitney clue, I would guess that (2) is the correct interpretation. In that case $k$ should be taken to be $\infty$, because I've never seen an instance of this exam which considers things that are differentiable but not smooth. (I am curious how it makes a difference, though!)

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: :/ :/ Thank you; what a silly oversight. This is probably the answer that was expected. If you can work this into an answer, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with an embedding as an infinity shape where the immersed circle crosses itself once. Take a round circle $C$ centered on the intersection which intersects the circle in 4 points. There are two intersecting subarcs $\eta_1,\eta_2$ supported on the interior of the circle.

Now suppose there is a nearby embedding $E$ of the immersed circle. It may cross the circle $C$ in messy intersections but one can look at the set of open subarcs of $E$ supported on the interior of $C$. Each of arcs $\eta_i$ is close to one of these open subarcs. We will call their closures $\tilde{\eta}_i$. Now note that because the endpoints of $\tilde{\eta}_i$ are close to those of $\eta_i$, their endpoints are still combinatorially linked. Thus these arcs embedded on the interior of $C$ must actually cross. (You can use the Jordan curve theorem to prove this!) This contradicts that we had an embedding.

Comment: I've spent the last half-hour trying to formalize this, and it seems to be kind of terrible. But I have gotten to the point that I see what your argument is, so this has been very helpful. Thanks for your patience :)