# Immersion that can't be approximated by an embedding

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

How do I construct an immersion $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that can't be approximated by an embedding? If the dimensions of the spaces would not fulfill the condition $2\cdot m=2\cdot 1=2=n$ there would be an approximation (cf. [Whitney immersion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem)).

I know that there is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822690/planar-immersion-of-circle-not-approximate-embedding) but frankly I don't understand the example that was given and there the immersion was defined on $S^1$ which is a one dimensional manifold but I need to construct one on $\mathbb{R}$.

Does someone know another example?

Comment: The intuition behind the other example is that a curve that crosses itself (transversally) will still have a crossing after a small perturbation, and fail to be injective. The same applies here.

Comment: @Kajelad That helped a lot. Could you please briefly sketch how I would formalize this?

Comment: Since it's it consists entirely of working on a small neighborhood around the crossing point, the argument from the linked answer will also work here.